# Enlarge pages of bibliography with more compressed entries

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, formatting

I have a bibliography that would fit perfectly on a number of pages except that there is one single entry too much. So LaTeX starts a new page just for that single entry.

In a normal document we can use `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` to tell LaTeX to "try a bit harder" to squeeze everything on one page. This works well and I have used it a number of times.

Can something similar be done for the bibliography? I just have the commands

```
\bibliography{someReferences}
\printbibliography
```

Putting the command right after that doesn't seem to work... Is something like this possible?

I don't want to change the general distance settings/font size of the bibliography. However I can see on some pages that there is more space left than on other pages so in theory the entries could be squeezed a bit more.

EDIT: it would be sufficient if the `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` is added just at the end of the bbl file, so right before the `\end{thebibliography}`. Is this possible without using a post-build script?

While the method by barbara beeton works, I would prefer a solution that works automatically...

Comment: Although it would get wiped out the next time you process the file, you could add the `\enlargethispage` to your `.bbl` file in the most appropriate place, usually the page with the widest gaps between bib entries.  And *don't* rerun bibtex.

Comment: I've been thinking about this problem a bit and I'm wondering whether a preamble-based setting for adjusting page sizes by page number. e.g., for each page you want to adjust you would put in the preamble, `\EnlargePage{47}{12pt}` or `\EnlargePage{23}{-12pt}`. It's a non-trivial change as I dig through source2e, but I think it is manageable. It would definitely require writing a new package.

Comment: (since the problem you encounter also comes up with any automatically generated extended text such as tables of contents, lists of figures, indices, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add to the bibenvironment definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\textheight4cm

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list{}
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\enlargethispage{3cm}\endlist} %or some other value
{\item}
\begin{document}
\cite{doody,herrmann}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is quite strange. If I use more citations, for example `\cite{testArticle1}, \cite{testArticle2}, \cite{testArticle3}, \cite{testArticle4}, \cite{testArticle5}` instead of `\cite{doody,herrmann}`, then only the first two are on the same page, somehow a new page is started for the references 3-5. Also I can't find the `\enlargethispage` command anywhere in the bbl file...

Comment: well I did set \textheight=4cm  for the test. And no the command doesn't go  in the bbl.

Comment: Ok got it, I didn't notice this was for testing only.